# How to select video and image both at the same time in iPhone app programmatically through JSON?

Tags: iphone

Can any body help me how to select video and image both at the same time in iphone app programmatically through JSON?

Here is my code:

```
urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://millioninone.cisusa.net/rest/index.php?c=save&m=savevideo"];
NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
//urlString=[urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"product.php?strJSON="];
NSString *filename = @"postVideo";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// if(imagedatabool)//ye image data ka object h jisme image jati h agar tujhe image nahi bjhna h to ye rehne dena

// {
NSString *str=@"/Users/CIS1/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0042.MP4";
videoData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];
// add the image form fields
// NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgView.image);
//NSLog(@"%@",imageData);


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just forming the request object.  You need to init the request against the NSUrlConnection object and implement the callback methods:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate

Here's a related SO post that was posting data:

[Posting to yFrog objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748553/posting-to-yfrog-objc/7748607#7748607)