# Switch from Synchronous request to Asynchronous request with image upload?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asynchronous

I need some help, i have been searching around and cant find the correct answer im looking for.

I am uploading images and videos to my server via php, When im uploading the video or image, i want to be able to show a progress view, i have been told that the only way to do this is to use asynchronous instead of synchronous. I have been looking at ways to set up this, but cant really seem to find a good tutorial that will help me with what im trying to accomplish.

Here is some code:

```
- (void)post:(NSData *)fileData
{


NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self saveUserLogin]];

int test;
NSString *string = [array objectAtIndex:3];
test = [string intValue];
test++;
NSData *videoData = fileData;
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.site.com/members/uploadMovie.php?&username=%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *postName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"vid%i.mov\"\r\n", test];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:postName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [array objectAtIndex:0],[array objectAtIndex:1], [array objectAtIndex:2], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", test], nil];
[values writeToFile:[self saveUserLogin] atomically:YES];
[self.delegate didFinishController:self];
}
```

this is some code that im using to send a video. filedata is a paramater being passed in with the video data. I want to animate a UIProgressview for the upload progress. I have also heard that apple likes people to use asynchronous anyways. If someone could please help me set up asynchronous instead of what i have, i would be really grateful. Please be specific if you reply, like to what i need to import what delegates, methods. etc.

Thank you very much :)

EDIT:

This is what it looks like now:

```
- (void)post:(NSData *)fileData
{


NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self saveUserLogin]];

int test;
NSString *string = [array objectAtIndex:3];
test = [string intValue];
test++;
NSData *videoData = fileData;
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.site.com/members/uploadMovie.php?&username=%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *postName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"vid%i.mov\"\r\n", test];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:postName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];


//NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
//NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    NSLog(@"connected");
    responceData = [NSMutableData data];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"error");
}
//  NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [array objectAtIndex:0],[array objectAtIndex:1], [array objectAtIndex:2], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", test], nil];
[values writeToFile:[self saveUserLogin] atomically:YES];
   // [self.delegate didFinishController:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[responceData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responceData     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"result: %@", responseString);

}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"error - read error object for details");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUrlConnection has an asynchronous request with callbacks.

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest
```

NSUrlConnection overview:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

That doc also points out you can get an estimation of upload progress by implementing a callback.

```
connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:
```

> **Estimating Upload Progress**
>
> You can estimate the progress of an HTTP POST upload with the
>   connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:
>   delegate method. Note that this is not an exact measurement of upload
>   progress, because the connection may fail or the connection may
>   encounter an authentication challenge.

Comment: I have coded out `returnData` and `returnString`, and have implemented what apple uses in the docs, 
`NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];`

I have also implemented some of the methods, and none of them are running and the file is not being uploaded. is there anything else i need to change?

Thanks for the reply

i have then also added the delegate to my .h file 
`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`

Comment: It's hard to say.  Here's another SO question on post where nothing happened.  Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748553/posting-to-yfrog-objc/7748607#7748607

Comment: I have added the methods, and made the changes that you answered in the other question, with still no luck. If you could please check the update and see if everything looks okay?

Comment: I have added the methods, and made the changes that you answered in the other question, with still no luck. If you could please check the update and see if everything looks okay?
Thanks :D